# How do I bring a Windows form to the front in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0

In my application when the user clicks on a label to open a form the form opens in the background.I mean it does not come to the front but is rather placed on taskbar. once the user cancels that instance of form and again clicks on the label,the form opens in foreground.Following portion of code does the specific work.

```
        if (DataFormDlg.Instance.InvokeRequired)
        {
            DataFormDlg.Instance.BeginInvoke(
                new ShowDataFormDelegate(ShowDataForm), pageId, timeout);
            return;
        }

        DataFormDlg.Instance.CurrentPageId = pageId;
        DataFormDlg.Instance.Timeout = timeout;

        if (!DataFormDlg.Instance.Visible)
            DataFormDlg.Instance.ShowDialog();
        else
            DataFormDlg.Instance.Focus();
```

Here the DataFormDlg is derived from windows form.

Comment: Did you try DataFormDlg,Instance.[BringToFront()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396);

Comment: yes..have tried that..

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the Parent property of the form?

Comment: @SteveWellens: The `Parent` property returns the container control of an embedded control. This is not the same as the owner form. It does not work in this situation.

Comment: InvokeRequired is the hint, you have a very serious bug in your program.  You are creating the form object on a worker thread.  That's for one why you had to use ShowDialog(), if you use Show() then it is a dead window.  For another that's why you have Z-order problems, the dialog will always pick the desktop window as the owner.  And you'll have lots of *very* nasty problems to come, requiring debugging that [looks like this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/).  Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the current form as owner to the `ShowDialog` method. The dialog form can then never get behind the first form, even if the user clicks on the first form.

Another consequence is that the second form closes automatically when the owner form closes. This is especially useful when the second form is opened with `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`.

```
DataFormDlg.Instance.ShowDialog(this);
```

using this overloaded version:

```
public DialogResult ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
```